# Can i implement an arrayList within an object

Tags: java, arraylist

I've been trying to make an object in Java that contains an `ArrayList`, but like I expected, when I implement a second object, it does not create a new `ArrayList`, rather adds existing date to the `ArrayList` generated when building the first object of the said type.

Here is constructor:

```
public class OneTest {

   private ArrayList<String> list;

   public OneTest(ArrayList<String> list) {
      this.list = list;
   }
}
```

The main method builds the object and adds data.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();
        array.add("Ben");
        array.add("Bob");

        OneTest test = new OneTest(array);

        ArrayList<String> array1 = new ArrayList<>();
        array.add("111");
        array.add("222");

        OneTest test1 = new OneTest(array1);

        ArrayList<String> testRecovery = test.getList();
        ArrayList<String> testRecovery1 = test1.getList();

        System.out.println(testRecovery.toString());
        System.out.println(testRecovery1.toString());
    }
```

And the output.

```
[]
[Ben, Bob, 111, 222]
```

I am looking for a way that when i call a toString() method, it has the numbers in a separate ArrayList for each object constructed.

Desired Output.

```
[Ben, Bob]
[111, 222]
```

Comment: You're adding the 111 and 222 to the first array, your code is fine.

Comment: You never add anything to `array1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the lines

```
ArrayList<String> array1 = new ArrayList<>();
array.add("111");
array.add("222");
```

you are adding `111` and `222` to `array` not `array1` meaning that `array1` will be empty.

If you update it to

```
ArrayList<String> array1 = new ArrayList<>();
array1.add("111");
array1.add("222");
```

when you reference the lists later they should be what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You are making such a silly mistake in below code :

```
array.add("111");
array.add("222");
```

Even after creating the second `arraylist` with `array1` , you are adding the values to the previous `arraylist` only `array`.

You need to change it to :

```
array1.add("111");
array1.add("222");
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting made quite a silly mistake, and added all to array, none to array1.